# Parsing HTML String to Blob - Salesforce Apex

Tags: html, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I have a simple html code that looks like this:

```html
 <html>
  <body>
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <img src="https://www.muycomputerpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/stack-overflow-brecha-seguridad.jpg" width="80" height="60" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a HTMLValue variable in an EmailTemplate record.
Whit Apex I Want to try to get this Html value and save in a Content Version,
but The parsing its no possible with the following code:

```
EmailTemplate  tmp = [SELECT Id, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate WHERE ID = '....' LIMIT 1];

ContentVersion cVersion = new ContentVersion();
cVersion.ContentLocation = 'S'; 
cVersion.PathOnClient = fileName + '.pdf';
cVersion.Title = fileName;
cVersion.Origin = 'H';
cVersion.OwnerId = caso.OwnerId;
cVersion.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode( EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.toPDF( tmp.HtmlValue )) );
Insert cVersion;
```

Its Fail when html has an image (img) inserted; there is a way to parse an html value to blob whithout lose information?